# Why not challenge the Oak?

Tags: opening

```
[Event "Rated Bullet game"]
[Site "https://lichess.org/SvddnsRp"]
[Date "2024.03.29"]
[White "Hannes150487"]
[Black "healLan"]
[Result "0-1"]
[UTCDate "2024.03.29"]
[UTCTime "15:26:51"]
[WhiteElo "1068"]
[BlackElo "1421"]
[WhiteRatingDiff "-14"]
[BlackRatingDiff "+2"]
[Variant "Standard"]
[TimeControl "60+0"]
[ECO "A01"]
[Opening "Nimzo-Larsen Attack: Classical Variation"]
[Termination "Time forfeit"]
[Annotator "lichess.org"]
[FEN ""]

1. b3 d5 { A01 Nimzo-Larsen Attack: Classical Variation } 2. Bb2 e6 3. e3 Bc5 4. Nf3 Bb6 5. Be2 Nc6 6. d3 Bd7 7. e4 Nf6 8. exd5 exd5 9. d4 O-O 10. c4 a6 11. cxd5 Nxd5 12. Nc3 Ba7 13. Nxd5 Be6 14. Bc4 Nxd4 15. Nxc7 Bd5 16. Bxd5 Rc8 17. Nxd4 Qe7+ 18. Qe2 Qxc7 19. O-O Rce8 20. f3 Rxe2 21. Bxf7+ Rxf7 22. Rfd1 Qc2 23. Kh1 Qxb2 24. Nc2 Qxc2 25. Rd8+ Rf8 26. Rad1 Rxg2 { Black wins on time. } 0-1
```